# OpenSSL CRL check in Tomcat rejects all connections

Tags: tomcat, openssl, x509certificate

I'm trying to add a check for revoked certificates in Tomcat through the crlFile attribute added to a TLS connector in the server.xml file.

Unfortunately this makes Tomcat reject all TLS connection requests even though their certificates are valid.

Any reason why?

**EDIT**

I turned on the java debug flags for SSL-only and I get this exception from the logs

```
16:50:14,348 INFO  [STDOUT] %% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
16:50:14,349 INFO  [STDOUT] http-127.0.0.1-8444-1
16:50:14,350 INFO  [STDOUT] , SEND TLSv1.1 ALERT:  
16:50:14,350 INFO  [STDOUT] fatal, 
16:50:14,351 INFO  [STDOUT] description = certificate_unknown
16:50:14,351 INFO  [STDOUT] http-127.0.0.1-8444-1, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Alert, length = 2
16:50:14,351 INFO  [STDOUT] http-127.0.0.1-8444-1, called closeSocket()
16:50:14,352 INFO  [STDOUT] http-127.0.0.1-8444-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Could not determine revocation status
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the expiration timestamp *of the CRL file*.

```
$ date -Is
2016-01-11T17:33:23+0100
$ openssl crl -text -noout -in crl.pem
Certificate Revocation List (CRL):
        Version 1 (0x0)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: <WHATEVER>
        Last Update: Dec 11 17:47:52 2015 GMT
        Next Update: Jan 10 17:47:52 2016 GMT
Revoked Certificates:
    Serial Number: 03
        Revocation Date: Dec 11 17:31:41 2015 GMT
    Serial Number: 04
        Revocation Date: Dec 11 17:47:52 2015 GMT
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         <CHECKSUM OMITTED>
```

If the `Next Update` time is in the past, then that's likely the cause of the problem. Bumping this expiration time into the future should solve it.

Unfortunately, OpenSSL doesn't seem to provide any easy way to just bump the expiration date; but [re-revoking an already revoked certificate](https://inuits.eu/blog/updating-crl-easy-rsa) using the [`easy-rsa`](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa) scripts from OpenVPN has the desired effect. This will be easier if you're already using `easy-rsa` to begin with, but it might still be possible even if you're not.

```
$ cd easy-rsa
$ source ./vars
$ ./revoke-full revokeme
Using configuration from /foo/easy-rsa/openssl-1.0.0.cnf
ERROR:Already revoked, serial number 03
Using configuration from /foo/easy-rsa/openssl-1.0.0.cnf
revokeme.crt: <DISTINGUISHED NAME HERE>
error 23 at 0 depth lookup:certificate revoked
```

Now deploy the `crl.pem` file in the Tomcat server and restart the server.

---

#### Background

I would have added this as a comment on the question, but since the question is over a year old it's unlikely OP is still experiencing the problem.

I use client certificates for authentication in a web application project, and everything was working just fine last friday. Today, on monday, all client certificates were apparently invalid despite no configuration had changed and no certificates had expired.

Removing the `crlFile` attribute from the `<Connector>` element in the Tomcat `server.xml` once again made client certificates pass the handshake, but of course this also made revoked certificates "valid" again since revocations were no longer checked. The procedure above solved the problem in my case.